# Quick Logs question - Use $\log_{24} 12$ to find $\log_{24} 2$

Tags: logarithms

Full Question is:

Given that $\log_{24} 12 =0.782$,  find the value of $\log_{24} 2$  .

How do I / should I set this out as well, formally?

Comment: Please post correct question.

Comment: Hint:  What is $\log_{24} 24$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\log_{24}12=\log_{24}\left(\frac{24}{2}\right)=\log_{24}24-\log_{24}2=1-\log_{24}2$$

Comment: By "hint" you mean "almost complete solution" ;-P

Comment: Even easier, start with $\log_{24}2=\log_{24}\frac{24}{12}$.

Comment: @DavidK: I think they are equivalent. The idea and the calculation. But in fact, it is another good point.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is exactly the same idea and steps, except that you don't need to follow it with "solve for $x$ in $0.782 = 1 - x$."

Comment: @Cicada: is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

$12=\dfrac{24}{2}$

$\log_{24} 12=\log_{24}{\frac{24}{2}}=\log_{24} 24 - \log_{24} 2$

$1-\log_{24}{2}= 0.782$

$\log_{24}{2} = 0.218$

Comment: Correct your calculation.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I can't say anything more than thanks !

Comment: You can now say thanks. Your welcome bro :-)

Comment: Note that if you start by observing that $2=\frac{24}{12}$ and proceed from there, you quickly get $\log_{24}2$ isolated on one side of an equation without the risk of errors while trying to solve $1-\log_{24}{2}= 0.782$.