# Logarithm-question: Using $\log_{24}(12)$ , find $\log_{24}(6)$

Tags: logarithms

Logarithm-question:

> Using $\log_{24}(12)$, find $\log_{24}(6)$

Thanks.

Comment: You have few minutes earlier ask same type of question. It means you are not getting basics behind that.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100388/quick-logs-question-use-log-24-12-to-find-log-24-2

Answer (score 4):

Let $\log_{24}12=x.$

Then $\log_{24}2=\log_{24}24-\log_{24}12=1-x.$

So $\log_{24}6=\log_{24}12-\log_{24}2=2x-1.$

Here's verification:

$(\log_{24}12)\cdot 2-1=\log_{24}12+\log_{24}12-\log_{24}24=\log_{24}(\frac{12\cdot 12}{24})=\log_{24}6.$

Comment: A numerical Value is needed.

Comment: Well, take whatever you had for $\log_{24}12$ and use y=2x-1 to get your answer.